# Increasing the resolution of Ubuntu 14.04 (nomachine)

Tags: 14.04, display, display-resolution, remote-desktop, nomachine

I am running a Ubuntu 14.04 on my VM at work. I have installed **Ubuntu Desktop** and **nomachine server**.

It was a quick installation. I connected to the server using nomachine MAC client. And the desktop was there. It was all working fine, until I realized, Ubuntu 14.40 doesn't come with **1920 x1080** resolution by default.

I have a constraint -> I cannot upgrade Ubuntu. It's a setup at work, I have to use it.

**1176 x 885** is the maximum resolution I get.

[image: Screenshot]

The screen looks so small. Making the Display 'Fit to Width' in nomachine settings pixelates the screen and its gets tough to work like that.

I have done -

```
admin@10-140-7-123:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Which adds the resolution to the list->

```
admin@10-140-7-123:~$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1176 x 885, maximum 1176 x 885
default connected primary 1176x885+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.0     85.0     75.0     72.0     56.0      0.0  
   1152x864      100.0     85.0     75.0     70.0     60.0      0.0  
   1024x768       85.0     75.0     70.0     60.0      0.0  
   832x624        75.0  
   640x480        85.0     75.0     73.0     60.0      0.0  
   720x400        85.0  
   640x400        85.0      0.0  
   640x350        85.0  
   320x240         0.0  
   400x300         0.0  
   512x384         0.0  
   854x480         0.0  
   720x480         0.0  
   720x576         0.0  
   320x200         0.0  
   800x480         0.0  
   1176x885        0.0* 
  1920x1080 (0x1e8)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

I'm not sure how to execute this command-

```
admin@10-140-7-123:~$ xrandr --addmode nomachinedisp 1920x1080
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "nomachinedisp"
```

What should be the value I have to enter instead of `nomachinedisp`? I don't know what my monitor's name is.

Here is what `monitors.xml` gives me.

```
admin@10-xxx-zzz-zzz:~$ cat ~/.config/monitors.xml 
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="default">
          <vendor>???</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1176</width>
          <height>885</height>
          <rate>0</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Any pointers on how to get proper 1920 x 1080 resolution with blur/pixelating?

---

**UPDATE:**

Steps/logs followed-

```
admin@10-140-7-123:~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

admin@10-140-7-123:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

admin@10-140-7-123:~$ xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "eDP-1"

admin@10-140-7-123:~$ xrandr -s 1920x1080
Size 1920x1080 not found in available modes
admin@10-140-7-123:~$
```

Output of `xrandr`:

```
admin@10-140-7-123:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1176 x 885, maximum 1176 x 885
default connected primary 1176x885+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.0     85.0     75.0     72.0     56.0      0.0  
   1152x864      100.0     85.0     75.0     70.0     60.0      0.0  
   1024x768       85.0     75.0     70.0     60.0      0.0  
   832x624        75.0  
   640x480        85.0     75.0     73.0     60.0      0.0  
   720x400        85.0  
   640x400        85.0      0.0  
   640x350        85.0  
   320x240         0.0  
   400x300         0.0  
   512x384         0.0  
   854x480         0.0  
   720x480         0.0  
   720x576         0.0  
   320x200         0.0  
   800x480         0.0  
   1176x885        0.0* 
  1920x1080 (0x1e8)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x212)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
admin@10-140-7-123:~$
```